# warning of unbound-anchor while configuring nettle library

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnutls

enter code hereI am trying to install nettle library.
So, first I installed GMP library. Then I am trying to configure nettle libray and I am getting the warning below.

```
DNSSEC root key file in /etc/unbound/root.key was not found
This file is nedded for the verification of DNSSEC responses.
Use the command: unbound-anchor -a "/etc/unbound/root.key"
to generate or update it.
```

I tried to give

```
$apt-get update
```

But I always get 0% progress. it will not increase. (it is not connected to internet.)
Should I connected to internet? If so, it is not possible for me because my development system is always offline. Any download option is available from where I can download from other system and transfer to my development system?

I also tried

```
$unbound-anchor - "/etc/unbound/root.key"
```

but it showed,

```
unbound-anchor: command not found
```

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when trying to compile `gnutls` on linuxmint.  I solved it by installing the "unbound" package.  Since linuxmint is based on debian this was:

`sudo apt-get install unbound`

Subsequent configure attempts indicated that I also needed the "libunbound-dev" package which might also apply when compiling nettle:

`sudo apt-get install libunbound-dev`